# natural deduction on proving a claim

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am working on this proof and wanted to know if I am using the ID natural deduction rule correctly. Can I just assume B and A based on that rule?

```
A ->(B->C)⊢ B->(A->C)

1. A -> (B->C) (given)
2. B (ID)
3. A (ID)
4. B -> C (->E 1,3)
5. C (->E 4,2)
6. A -> C (->I 3,5)
7. B->(A->C) (->I 2,6)
QED
```

Comment: This is correct, but what you call "ID" is not a rule. Rather, you introduce assumptions that get discharged later (in steps 6, 7).

Comment: ahh ok. are my assumptions valid? what constitutes a valid assumption?

Comment: @user2510809 All propositional well-formed formulas can stand as assumptions, including contradictions and tautologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've used "ID" correctly (though I haven't seen the rule called "ID" before, and I don't know what it says exactly).

That said, when you used ->I you didn't just use steps 3 and 5 as your proof analysis suggests.  You used *all* of the steps from 3 to 5.  So, you'll want to notate that differently than you did... probably >I 3-5 for step 6. and >I 2-6 for step 7.  Seeing that you used all of the steps here might come as clearer in an axiomatic context where you can prove the Deduction Meta-Theorem.

Comment: Identity/reflexivity: A ⊢ A    <---- that is what I mean by ID